# Why isn't my ggplot graph showing up on shiny?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

Hello I'm doing this Shiny app for a class project and I was wondering why my graph isn't appearing at all. It runs without giving me an error and shows the side panels, but the graph is appearing blank. I've attached the code below. I've seen other posts on here that deal with us and I've tried them out, but nothing has been giving me the results I need. I just need this to show up by Tuesday, so I can present it on Thursday morning. Thank you!

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.

# Load Libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(quantmod) 


# Load and Merge Data

wordbank = read_csv("/Users/Dohyun/Desktop/school stuff/year3/stat41/final project/administration_data.csv")

wordbank

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Word Bank"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with a input and output definitions
  sidebarLayout(
    # Inputs: Select variables to plot
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput(inputId = "x", 
                  label = "X-axis:",
                  choices = c("Age" = "age")),
      
      selectInput(inputId = "y", 
                  label = "Y-axis:",
                  choices = c("Word Size" = "comprehension")),
      
      
      selectInput(inputId = 'language', 'Language: ', 
                     choices = c("English (American)", "English (British)", "English (Australian)",
                                 "American Sign Language","British Sign Language",
                                 "Cantonese","Croatian","Czech", "Danish", "French (French)",
                                 "French (Quebecois)", "German", "Greek (Cypriot)", "Hebrew",
                                 "Italian", "Kigiriama", "Kiswahili", "Korean", "Latvian",
                                 "Mandarin (Beijing)", "Mandarin (Taiwanese", "Norwegian",
                                 "Portugeuse (European)", "Russian", "Slovak", "Spanish (European)",
                                 "Spanish (Mexican)", "Swedish", "Turkish")),
      
      sliderInput(inputId = "alpha", 
                  label = "Alpha:", 
                  min = 0, max = 1, 
                  value = 0.5)
      
    
    ),
    
    #Output
    
    mainPanel(
      
      plotOutput(outputId = "scatterplot"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "boxplot"),
      br(),        # a little bit of visual separation
      
    )
  )
)

# Define server function --------------------------------------------
server <- function(input, output) {

  lang_data <- reactive({
    wordbank %>%
      filter(language %in% input$language)
  })
  
  # Create scatterplot object the plotOutput function is expecting
  output$lang_plot <- renderPlot({
 
    # Creates base plot 
 
    p1 <-
      ggplot(lang_data(), aes(x = input$x, y = input$y, fill = as.factor(age))) +
        geom_boxplot(alpha = .6, outlier.shape = NA) + 
        geom_jitter(size = 0.2, alpha = input$alpha, width = 0.3, aes(color = as.factor(age))) +
        scale_fill_viridis_d(end = .75, option = "D", guide=FALSE) +
        scale_color_viridis_d(end = .75, option = "D", guide=FALSE) +
        labs(x = str_to_title(str_replace_all(input$x, "_", " ")),
             y = str_to_title(str_replace_all(input$y, "_", " "))) +
        scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(from = 16, to = 30, by = 2)) 
        theme(panel.background = element_blank())
      
      print(p1)

  })
  
  
}

# Create the Shiny app object ---------------------------------------
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You may change the `aes` to `aes(x = .data[[input$x]], y = .data[[input$y]],` or convert to `sym`bol and evaluate (`!!`) i.e. `aes(x = !! rlang::sym(input$x), y = !! rlang::sym(input$y),`

Comment: or use `aes_string(x=input$x, ...)`, since their strings (the *intent* of `aes_string`). (Per @akrun's comment, though, it might be useful to think of your shiny app as a *package* and heed `ggplot2`'s recommendations for [*"Using ggplot2 in packages"*](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/articles/ggplot2-in-packages.html).)

Comment: Also since we don't have access to `/Users/Dohyun/Desktop/school stuff/year3.....` it would be better to share your data in a reproducible format to make this code working for us. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).